# jQuery click event still firing on filtered element

Tags: jquery, events, css-selectors

I'm trying to filter button events based on whether they have a CSS class assigned to them or not.

Assume I have a button like this:

```
<button id="save-button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Save</button>
```

I want to get jQuery to select all buttons that currently *do not* have a class of "ui-state-disabled".  The selector I'm using looks like this:

```
$('#save-button:not(.ui-state-disabled)').click(function() {
   ...
});
```

When the button is clicked, I'll call a different function, do some stuff and then add the class 'ui-state-disabled' to the button.  However the button still continues to accept click events.

I'm guessing this is because of two possible causes:

1. The event binder looks only at the initial state when binding the click event and doesn't recognise that a new class has been added later on
2. My filter ['... :not(.ui-state-disabled)] is not correct

Any observations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to do what you want, like this:

```
$('#save-button:not(.ui-state-disabled)').live('click', function() {
   ...
});
```

Or, check for the class when the `click` handler fires, like this:

```
$('#save-button').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-disabled')) return;
  ...
});
```

Your #1 is correct for the reason, the selector finds the elements that match **at that time** and binds a click handler to them...doesn't matter what classes or IDs they have later, the handler is bound to the element.  `.live()` listens for bubbles and checks that the selector matches **when the event happens**, so it works...or you check yourself inside the `click` handler like I have in the second option above.